# ANTLR: How to write a rule for enforcing line continuation character while writing a string?

Tags: string, antlr4

I want to write a rule for parsing a string inside double quotes. I want to allow any character, with the only condition being that there MUST be a line continuation character \, when splitting the string on multiple lines.

Example:

```
variable = "first line \n second line \
            still second line \n \
            third line"
```

If the line continuation character is not found before a newline character is found, I want the parser to barf.

My current rule is this:

```
STRING  : '"' (ESC|.)*? '"';
fragment ESC : '\\' [btnr"\\] ;
```

So I am allowing the string to contain any character, including bunch of escape sequences. But I am not really enforcing that line continuation character \ is a necessity for splitting text.

How can I make the grammar enforce that rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

```
fragment ESCAPE
    : '\\' .
    ;
STRING
    : '"' (ESCAPE | ~[\n"])* '"'
    ;
```

## Explanation

Fragment `ESCAPE` will match escaped characters (especially backslash and a new line character acting as a continuation sign).

Token `STRING` will match inside double quotation marks:

- Escaped characters (fragment `ESCAPE`)
- Everything except new line and double quotation marks.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! But the issue is I do want user to be able to write \r, \n, \" in the string. Since the string is enclosed in double quotes, the user needs to escape the double quote if he wants to embed it into the string. Like "first line \n second line \"inside quotes\" "

Comment: What I mean is, user can embed backslash followed by r, n or " in the string. But he cannot literally press Enter while defining the string in his program, without having the continuation character. How do I differentiate between user written backslash+n, and the one that gets added to the string when he presses Enter in his editor (in fact on Windows, \r\n gets added)

Comment: Thanks again! :) I tried this out. Looks like \r and \n are consumed correctly, and I see errors when line continuation is not followed by "Enter". But \" does not work. Example:

    `"this is a long description\
     should yield error if line continuation is missing on splits \
     but \n \r \"should be fine\"\
     "`

Comment: Ok I made a last update to the solution. How about now? :)

Comment: This works now because line continuation character need not be followed by a new line. So the STRING matches either a backslash followed by anything, or any character that is not \n or "
I can definitely live with this. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 3):

Even though there is already an accepted answer let me put in my 2cents. I strongly recommend not to handle this type of error in a lexer rule. The reason is that you will not be able to give the user a good error message. First, lexer errors are usually not reported separately in ANTLR4, they appear as follow up parser errors. Second, the produced error (likely something like: "no viable alt at \n") is all but helpful.

The better solution is to accept both variants (linebreak with or w/o escape) and do a semantic check afterwards. Then you know exactly what is wrong and can the user tell what you really expected.

Comment: This was how I had implemented it initially. My STRING would match absolutely anything within double quotes. But as I started to enforce restrictions, I realized it would be more messy for me to semantically check for those restrictions manually, rather than embedding the rules inside the grammar.
As for lexer errors, I recently learnt that I can override ErrorListener and ErrorStrategy python classes and tune the error handling the way I want. So I will be looking into that. Thanks for the insight though!